# Self-service password reset (SSPR) - Lockout user account with multiple attempts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In self-service password reset (SSPR), to prevent users from multiple attempts to reset a password, if user try only five wrong password reset attempts it lock user for 24 hours. I would like to confirm, if there is a way for Admins to reset the counter for the locked user account and/or unblock user to login to the Azure portal?

Reference article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/active-directory-passwords-faq

In the scenario, where a bad actor try to lock some user’s then it could easily be done by knowing the username and users will not be able to login for 24 hours. Is there a way to prevent it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07to.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTKG4.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Administrator can block/unblock users from Azure portal. To do that login to Azure portal from administrator account. Go to Azure Active Directory --> User Section. Select particular user and edit the setting section and select "Yes" to **Block sign in** the user. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Above process is same for Azure AD B2C.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying but when user gets locked with SSPR multiple attempts, "block sign-in" does not change. It remain at NO. Try that!

Comment: Please review and test at your end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know which user role you have when you are logging into the portal? I tried it with "Global Administrator" role and I am able to do it.

Comment: I tried with my GA account as well and it did not work. I used a Test account for SSPR and at validation, i tried 5 wrong attempts to validate my phone number which result in account lockout as expected. Then with my GA account, i logged in to the portal and the block sign-in is "NO".  Which means even with GA access, i cannot unblock user to login.

Comment: I have added images in my question for reference. I noticed, in your image, you mention to select "Yes" to block sign-in?? Yes, will block. I as an admin, looking to unlock which means it should be at at "NO". Am i missing something in explaining it?

Comment: Changing to Yes, will surely block. I want to reset counter for a user who tried multiple wring attempts by mistake and now as a admin i want to help user to login to the azure portal.

Comment: In my screenshot, it is selected as 'No", it means user is not blocked. If we select "Yes" means user is blocked.

Comment: That what i meant. Even after the blocked sign-in after wrong attempts, the "Block Sign-in" property for the user account remain "NO". Hope it makes sense to you now.